# Laravel 5.2 php artisan routes not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

In Laravel 5.2, trying to display the routes list using `php artisan routes`. But, its not working. It will show the below errors,

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>     Command "routes" is not defined.

How to fix this issue??

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lumen - Missing commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080610/lumen-missing-commands)

Answer (score 7):

It is `php artisan route:list` since Laravel 5.1

**UPDATE**

It seems you're using Lumen, not Laravel. Unfortunately there are not many commands in Lumen, so if you really need to use them, you can create them or just use Laravel framework instead of Lumen.

Or you can use package like:

https://github.com/sohelamin/lumen-route-list

Comment: Its also not working it showing error like `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "route" namespace.  `

Comment: If you run `php artisan` command, it will display all available commands. Please try,

Comment: Yes am running `php artisan` but not found `route` in that list

Comment: It seems not everything was installed. Try to run `composer install`. Does it generate any error?

Comment: Its an up-to-date, its shows `Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
`

Comment: Did you install Laravel 5.2, or you did upgrade from Laravel 4? If it's clean installation, I'd reccomend reinstall Laravel. If not, all I can reccomend is to reinstall all packages: https://www.dev-metal.com/composer-problems-try-full-reset/ - this will delete `vendor` directory and reinstall all packages.